# Passing HTML name value into rails select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that has a select field where the user selects their title. I want to pass a name value into the rails code so the field can be modified with a client-side validation framework. The client-side validations validate each field based on the name of the field.

My current solution isn't passing the name value of 'title' into the final HTML rendered in the browser.

**The field**

```
<%= f.select :title, options_for_select([["Title", "0"], ["Mr.", "Mr."], ["Mrs.", "Mrs."], ["Ms.", "Ms."], ["Dr.", "Dr."], ["Prof.", "Prof."]], selected: "0", disabled: ["0"]), :name => "title" %>
```

**The current HTML output**

```
name="user[title]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% possible_options =  [["Title", "0"], ["Mr.", "Mr."], 
      ["Mrs.", "Mrs."], ["Ms.", "Ms."], ["Dr.", "Dr."], ["Prof.", "Prof."]]
    %> 

<%= f.select :title, options_for_select(possible_options), {}, {:name => "title"} %>
```

It's better to prepare this possible_optins list in controller action itself & accessing here just like an instance variable.

Just for a quick fix, let it be in this view/form.

Comment: Also, wouldn't it need to be @possible_options to list the options in the controller? <% %> would be if I wanted the variable set inside the view, correct?

Comment: Yes exactly! if you are defining @possible_options in your controllers action then it'll be available to that action + the view of that action. 
But if you are defining it as an instance variable in view(just as we are doing <% %> then it's available only in View.